# Dice and Probability. Did I do this question correctly?

Tags: probability

This is a homework problem.

Two fair dice are rolled.
A = At least one die shows 1, B = The sum of the dice is 6

P(At least one) = $1$ - P(none) = $1$ - $5/6$ * $5/6$ = $1$ - $25/36$ = $11/36$

P(Sum of dice is six) = $(1,5)$, $(2,4)$, $(3,3)$, $(5,1)$, $(4,2)$, $(3,3)$ = $6/36$ = $1/6$

My answer: $P(A \bigcap B)$ = $11/36$ * $1/6$ = $11/216$

Comment: In sum of dice is $6$ (event $B$) you should only count the outcome $(3,3)$ one time.

Comment: @paw88789, I was wondering about that since you can't distinguish the numbers. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the events are not independent so multiplying them out doesn't work.

Think of the sample space and the outcomes in there that work. Namely, the only combinations that satisfy both conditions are:

(1,5)
(5,1)

There are 36 total outcomes. That means the probability is 2/36 = 1/18.

Comment: Ok I forgot about independence but I did think of it like a venn diagram and drew it out with those two numbers intersecting however I got confused as to why other examples I've seen do the product of the numbers. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @jc707270, no problem. I'm glad to help :-).